# Search using REST endpoints in php and mysql

Tags: php, json

A requests from ionic app was passed to REST Web API with the following service method parameters:

```
http://localhost:83/api/products?
searchCriteria[filter_groups][0][filters][0][field]=category_id& 
searchCriteria[filter_groups][0][filters][0][value]=17
```

in my php, I am trying to get the **value** which is **17**. When I tried to print out the value by doing the following:

```
echo searchCriteria[filter_groups][0][filters][0][value];
```

I have

> Notice: Undefined index:
>   searchCriteria[filter_groups][0][filters][0][value]

How can I get the **field** and **value** in php?

Comment: Please, read: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask
Your question is not clear and we can't investigate deeper in your localhost.

Comment: @ncesar Could you please look at the updated question.